# Can anyone tell me why I'm getting null when using to_date hive (version 1.2) function?

Tags: hadoop, null, hive, to-date

all

I created an external table in my Hive 1.2 database. Check 5 first rows:

```
hive> select dt_locacao from locacao_aux_externa limit 5;
OK
'2010-11-21'
'2009-03-20'
'2010-02-16'
'2012-12-20'
'2017-12-19'
Time taken: 0.253 seconds, Fetched: 5 row(s)
```

However, if I try to use to_date function...

```
hive> select to_date(dt_locacao) from locacao_aux_externa limit 5;
OK
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
NULL
```

Notice that I used the correct format: YYYY-MM-DD.

And, more surprisingly, when I pick just one date...

```
hive> select to_date('2010-11-21');
OK
2010-11-21
Time taken: 0.187 seconds, Fetched: 1 row(s)
```

I got the expected result (no matter if I use single or double quotes)

Just to clarify, I've gotten this error while trying to load external data to an ORC one.

Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: dt_locacao data seems to be qualified (`´`)

Comment: `select to_date(replace(dt_locacao,"'","")) from locacao_aux_externa limit 5;` - try this

Comment: Unfortunately, it did not work. This function "replace" was introduced in version 1.3 and I am using 1.2 (installed in Hortnworks Sandbox 2.5).

Comment: Also I had already tried replacing single quotes by double quotes, but with no success

Answer (score 0):

if replace is not in your version, try this

```
select to_date(regexp_replace("'2010-11-21'","'",""));
```

Comment: your welcome, you always can mark the answer as good to help others:p